# Уместны ли "двое" в этом контексте?

Tags: грамотная-речь, собирательные-числительные

Я вернулся к кассе и сказал женщине:

— Я за ними двоими.

Двое были девушками. Понятно, что нельзя сказать "двое девушек", а только "две девушки", но можно сказать "двое/трое мужчин". Но ведь я произнёс только числительное без слова "девушки", поэтому и спрашиваю. Всегда казалось, что так можно говорить независимо от пола, однако хочется убедиться наверняка.

Comment: Я бы сказал "я за **этими двумя**". Мне не нравится и "двое" по отношению к барышням, и вне определенного контекста "они двое" по отношению к лицам любого пола. Причем даже не знаю, что больше. Подробнее сейчас не могу, если с силами соберусь , то попозже отвечу предметно.

Comment: @behemothus: спасибо, что кратко изложили своё отношение! Хм, а мне кажется что "этот", "эти" без указания, кто именно "этот", невежливо. По крайней мере меня так мама научила и уверен, что, если её спрошу, она будет горячо отстаивать эту позицию и отвергать "этих" самих по себе. Сам думаю, что в ответ на вопрос "Вы за какими девушками?" можно сказать "А за этими двумя" даже в присутствии самих девушек, но не знаю, согласится ли мама.

Comment: Что-то уж слишком сложно: жестикуляцию, мимику и пр. невербальные способы передачи примитивной информации никто не отменял. Ну а ответ "За двумя" правилен будет лишь на вопрос "За сколькими?". Кроме того, ситуация должна затрагивать минимум людей, и точно не впереди находящихся. Предупреждают, как правило, дождавшись следом пришедших и убедившись, что о вас не забудут тут же, чтобы возвращение ваше не обернулось новостью и выяснением отношений. Оно будет связано лишь с кратким напоминанием той самой «женщине» (помните меня, я отходил?) и добрым словом (спасибо, выручили).

Comment: Я часто не дожидаюсь следующего и её тогда тоже не дождался.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Но ведь я произнёс только числительное без слова "девушки"
```

Да, произнесли без указания на личности, но имели в виду всё-таки девушек. Артём, Вы употребили ситуативно-неполное предложение. Не назван член предложения, ясный из ситуации: *Я надену это синее. (К.Федин*) По обстановке мы знаем, что платье.

*- Вам с мясом или с капустой?* И мы понимаем, что речь о пирожках, потому что спрашивает продавец пирожков.

Вот и здесь все видят, что речь о девушках, значит, и правила о собирательных числительных нужно применять с учётом женского пола личностей, о которых идёт речь.

Так что  ***— Я за ними двоими***   будет некорректно. Учитывая правила тона (вежливость/воспитанность), сама фраза невежлива по отношению к девушкам (они же рядом и слышат). Если так важно указать число, можно сказать: "***Я за этими двумя девушками***". Или уж вовсе без числительного, если лень тратить слова: ***- Я вот за ними***.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! А почему "Я вот за ними" вежливо, а если добавить "двумя" — нет? Согласен с первой частью отчасти только: в примерах с платьем и пирожками можно вставить эти слова (они просто пропущены), а в моей фразе при наличии слова "ними" уже не вставишь "девушками". "Ними" берёт, что ли, на себя смысловую нагрузку, которую могли бы нести "девушки", если б упоминались.

Comment: Артём, это невежливо, потому что звучит обезличенно, а девушки требуют к себе внимания как к личности. "Я вот за ними" будет сопровождаться жестом - всем понятно, что они ему чужие, незнакомые, интересуют его только для уточнения порядка очереди, а "Я за ними двумя" - не просто незнакомые, они ему вообще безразличны (девушки они, или дети, или бомжи), важна только цифра. Это обидно. Если нужно указать цифру, возможно сказать "Я за ними обеими" - всё хоть указание на пол, а то звучит так же, как "их двоих забираю на работы". Не люди, расходный материал.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила, что объяснили!